# Why does the borrow from `HashMap::get` not end when the function returns?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Here is emulation of my problem, when a borrow ends too late

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Item {
    capacity: u64
}

struct Petrol {
    name: String,
    fuel: HashMap<&'static str, Item>
}

fn buy_gaz(p: &mut Petrol) {
   match p.fuel.get("gaz") {
      Some(gaz) => {
        fire_petrol(p); 
      }
      None => ()
   }
}

fn fire_petrol(p: &mut Petrol) {
    println!("Boom!");
    p.fuel.remove("gaz");
    p.fuel.remove("benzin");
}

fn main() {
    let mut bt = Petrol {
        name: "Britii Petrovich".to_string(),
        fuel: HashMap::new()
    };

    bt.fuel.insert("gaz", Item { capacity: 1000 });
    bt.fuel.insert("benzin", Item { capacity: 5000 });

    buy_gaz(&mut bt);
}
```

When compiling I get:

```
note: previous borrow of `p.fuel` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `p.fuel` until the borrow ends
match p.fuel.get("gaz") {
      ^~~~~~
```

Why does the borrow end so late and not on exit from `HashMap::get`? How do I fix my case?

PS: I edited my first post for adding struct to `HashMap`, because decision below worked for simply types (with default Clone trait, I think), but doesn't work for custom structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of `HashMap::get`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) you can see, that it returns an `Option<&V>`. The reference into the map allows you to do zero-copy accesses into a hash-map. The downside is, as long as you have a reference, you cannot modify the hash map as that might invalidate your reference.

The branch `Some(gaz)` causes the binding `gaz` to have type `&u64`, where the reference points into your hashmap. If you change that to `Some(&gaz)` you get a copy of the value instead of a reference, and may modify the hash map even inside that branch.

[Minimal Example in Playpen](http://is.gd/rNeCc9)

Comment: Excuse me, but I have more complicated structure, what do in such case  [Play.Rust](http://is.gd/KTNUGm) ?

Comment: I would make my structure copyable, by adding `#[derive(Copy)]` before the struct definition: http://is.gd/nrBnMk

Comment: if you truly have a non-copyable structure, then you can use [`remove`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) instead of `get`, which removes the value from the map and returns it

Comment: I don't want to copy my structure(. But if I use `remove` I change a `HashMap `and I just want to get value and nothing more. And this value I cannot copy. Only such decisions exist?

Comment: if you get the value, you may not modify the hash-map. so you cannot call a function that wants `&mut self`. Most likely you can work around your issue. but since `fire_petrol` doesn't use `gaz`, you could simply call `fire_petrol` after the match and have the `None=>()` branch be `None=>return` instead

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's not what I want, but I've understood the concept